# Way to make Minecraft less grind-y?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

I enjoy all the engineering mods, and I wanna spend my time setting up stuff like factories and breeding facilities, but I found that I'm mostly mining for various crap.

I don't wanna switch over to Creative because that changes unrelated mechanics like Hunger, and I like having to unlock access to new material. I just wish I didn't have to farm for so much stuff.

Is there a mod or something to fix that? Maybe something that massively improves yield for all the common materials?

Comment: ComputerCraft. Have Turtles do the farming for you. :)

Comment: There are generally numerous ways to gather materials or process them into more materials with all the engineering mod out there.

Comment: big rig... all ores can spawn at surface level, and there is alot of crap in there to.

Comment: Try feed the beast, it is a mod package with a ton of content. MC feels a lot more expansive and there is so much to do, as a side effect it feels less "grindy". It includes computer craft for turtle mining, buildcraft for quarries and much more. There are special "ovens" too that duplicate the raw resources you find, go for those first, then enchant a diamond pickaxe with silk touch and minerals should be not much of a problem anymore.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're tired of *mining* for ores, and instead want to focus on building take a look at Quarries. It is expensive in terms of minecraft resources, but once you build one, you won't have to mine anymore.

> The Quarry block allows you to excavate a large area without much
>   manual intervention. Once placed and powered, the quarry structure
>   will be automatically built and will begin to mine the area.

http://minecraftbuildcraft.wikia.com/wiki/Quarry

Comment: @muflax there are other automated mining solutions, going from an army of turtles to arcane bores moved periodically

Answer (score 3):

If you are still manually mining then you arent using those factory mods effectively ;)

between [Buildcraft Quarries](http://minecraftbuildcraft.wikia.com/wiki/Quarry), [Industrial Craft Miners](http://feed-the-beast.wikia.com/wiki/Miner)(personal preferred), [Arcane Bore](http://feed-the-beast.wikia.com/wiki/Arcane_Bore), [Mining Turtles](http://feed-the-beast.wikia.com/wiki/Mining_Turtle), and many others. Mining in engineering modded minecraft is pretty automonous, and the main fun(imo) of the mods is getting a complex super mining->refining->smelting->sorting system completely automated